# Parametric equation of degree 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to solve the following problem without derivatives.

Prove that the equation $x^4+x^2-ax-3=0$ has 2 real roots for all possible values of a. If the sum of the roots is 1, find $a$.

Comment: What have u tried? any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Are you familiar with [Descartes' Rule of Signs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs)?

Answer (score 2):

Compare the graphs of $x^3+x$ and $a+3/x$.  Why would there be two solutions for any $a$?

Comment: A nice argument.

Comment: A little more explanation for mere mortals like me please.

Comment: They are equal when the original equation is true.  One is increasing, one is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1 , x_2$ be real roots, and $x_3, x_4$ be complex roots.

$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 0$,and $x_1 + x_2 = 1$, therefore $x_3 + x_4 = -1$.
Let, $x_3 = m + ni$ and $x_4 = m - ni$. $ \; m,n \in \mathbb{R}$.

$x_3 + x_4 = 2m = -1$, therefore $m=\frac{-1}{2}$.
$x_1 x_2 + x_1 x_3 + x_1 x_4 + x_2 x_3 + x_2 x_4 + x_3 x_4 =1$, therefore $x_1 x_2 + (x_1 + x_2)(x_3 + x_4) + x_3 x_4 = x_1 x_2 + 1 \times (-1) + (\frac{1}{4} + n^2 ) = 1$
$x_1 x_2 + n^2 = \frac{7}{4}$
$x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 = -3 \; \Rightarrow \; (\frac{7}{4} - n^2 ) ( \frac{1}{4} + n^2) = -3$
There are two real solutions $n_{1,2} = \pm \frac{\sqrt{11}}{2}$. Therefore, $x_1x_2 = -1$.

And $x_1 x_2 x_3 + x_1 x_2 x_4 + x_1 x_3 x_4 + x_2 x_3 x_4 = a$.
$x_1 x_2 (x_3 + x_4 ) + (x_1 + x_2 )x_3 x_4 = a$.

You can do the rest.....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Consider that the problem is to find the intesections of the curve $$y=x^4+x^2-3$$ and the straight line $y=ax$ which goes throught the origin. Notice that on the curve, you have $y=-3$ when $x=0$.

I am sure that you can take from here.